# Passing NSString value between classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, nsstring

I have been looking long for a solution how to pass the value from one class to another. Basically I create a NSString via @property in a Settings class, which is displayed modally. I then set the NSString to a certain value depending on the settings chosen, and I want to have the value shown also in a class where the settings are supposed to make change. I also declare a string via @property in the second class, and I use the code

```
myController *controller = [[myController alloc] init];
secondClassString = controller.firstClassString
```

If I NSLog the string, it shows (null) in the second class... 
Any ideas how to make it pass the value? Thanks

Comment: I know how to pass an array, done it many times, and I was googling my case for hours, yet I found no working solution how to pass a NSString value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose you've two viewcontrollers say **A** & **B**

**Your A.h**

```
{
  NSString *strData;
  int cId;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strData;
@property (readwrite) int cId;
```

**Now In your A.m**

```
@synthesize strData,cId;
```

**Your B.h**

```
@class A

{
   A *aObj;
}
```

**Now In your B.m**

```
#import "A.h"

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
  aObj=[A alloc] init]; //alloc object of A
  [aObj setCId:10]; //set value for cId
  [aObj setStrData:@"Hello from B"]; //set value for strData
  //do what ever
  [aObj release]; //don't forget
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: You shouldn't post answers that are just links.

Comment: @yuji, I thought I could save some space for SO. I've posted my answer.

Comment: Perfect, i just dont quite understand what is the cId for.

Comment: @DenisBalko,  I used two different types of variables to pass values between to class. You can pass almost any type of values using set & get.

Answer (score 2):

first view controller:

nsstring *firstString=@"your string";
 to pass this string into second view controllert create nsstring into 2nd view controller
in 2nd view controller

```
nsstring *sencondstring;
```

@property(nonatomic,retain)nsstring *sencondstring;
@synthesize sencondstring;

now back to first view controller create object of second view controller

```
firstviewcontroller *firstviewObj=[[firstviewcontroller  alloc]init;
```

firstviewObj.sencondstring=firststring; OR 
firstviewObj.sencondstring=[nsstring stringwithformat:@"%@",firststring];

Comment: Whats different from my answer? Whole basic syntax and flow is same as my answer. Even you have used same variable names and view controller names. I think you should not copy answers. I would like to flag it to the moderator

Answer (score 0):

maybe this would help you

write this in Firstclass.m file

```
SecondView *ObjSecondView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];

objSecondView.secondClassString=Firstclassstring;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ObjSecondView animated:YES];
[ObjSecondView release];
```

in SecondView.h

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *secondClassString;
//also synthesize this
```

then print on secondview's viewdidload method

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
NSLog(@"your string = %@",secondClassString);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Let us use the names of the two viewControllers as FirstViewController and SecondViewController.

Now suppose you push SecondViewController from FirstViewController on a button click then you need to write this code under your button click event:

```
 //   In the FirstViewController

- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender{

    SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle: nil];
 second.secString = firstString;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
 [second release];

}
```

Here you need to declare in `SecondViewController.h` file:

```
NSString *secString;
```

and then create a `@property`

```
@property (non atomic,strong) NSString *secString;
```

In `SecondViewController.m` you need to `@synthesize` the `secString`:

```
@synthesize secString;
```

Hence this way you also create a getter and setter for secString by creating property and synthesizing it.

Now you can easily access the `secString` and you can use it anywhere in SecondViewController.

Just to check Try and check if value of firstString is passed to secString, write following code on `viewWillAppear:` of `SecondViewController`

```
NSLog(@"secString: %@",secString);
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually it is a little bit more complicated... I have a UITableView with a navigation controller. At the first view there is a bar button that shows the settings modally, which are after pressing save dismissed. I then have to navigate through the navigation controller to get to the view that I need to pass the value to.

Comment: @DenisBalko: Sorry but I don't get the flow. Can you please post screen shots of your views in your question? That would better explain it.

Comment: @DenisBalko: You need to get the values in some variables of the viewController (the one with TableView and NavigationController), when you click save on settings page and dismiss it. And then you can apply my solution