# How do I link an array between two ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm a beginner at C# so make sure you explain everything.

Okay, so I have a `UIPickerView` with its corresponding array of items in my `ViewController`. When the user clicks "submit", the app is supposed to take them to a `SecondViewController`, and display the item that they chose in the `UIPickerView` in a label. The only problem I am having is that I can't seem to link the two ViewControllers together.

I imported my `ViewController` by using `#import` into the `SecondViewController`, but that didn't work. I am getting a "use of undeclared identifer' error. What am I supposed to do to link the two `ViewController`s together?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we assume you mean `Objective-C` and not `C#`?

Answer (score 0):

If your first ViewController is the one that's presenting your second ViewController, then you can add a property in the second-view-controller that will be set to the selected value.

In `SecondViewController.h`

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *selectedItemName;
```

Then, when you're presenting your second-view-controller, also set the value for this property:

```
SecondViewController *vc2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

vc2.selectedItemName = @"selected item"; //set the actual selected item's value here
[self presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
```

Comment: I added the property in my second ViewController.h, but I'm a bit confused on where to put the second part. A button is linked from the first ViewController to the second ViewController with a modal. When the button is clicked, it takes the user to the second ViewController and is supposed to display text based on which option they picked. So am I supposed to put the second part within the second ViewController, or..?

Comment: You need to put this code when the button is clicked, where you instantiate the second view-controller. Look at the method handler for the button click.

Comment: Oh okay, where do I find the method handler for the button? I tried to make a new IBAction for the button and added what you posted, and it built successfully, but I got a warning when clicking submit that said "Attempted to present while a presentation is in progress." The label on the SecondViewController did not change. I assume that I need to go to the code where it presents the SecondViewController with the modal, but I'm not sure where to find that. I tried to google it with no luck. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: How was the second viewcontroller being presented before you added in my code? It looks like it was already happening by some code you didn't explicitly write. (That's why when you try to present the VC again, you get the warning "Attempt to present...")
Try to find out how the second VC is getting presented. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer by Parth Bhatt. I think that should help you:

[Passing NSString value between classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954155/passing-nsstring-value-between-classes/9954383#9954383)

I am re-pasting the answer to make the answer useful in case the link goes off in the future.

**Answer from the above link:**

Let us use the names of the two viewControllers as FirstViewController and SecondViewController.

Now suppose you push SecondViewController from FirstViewController on a button click then you need to write this code under your button click event:

```
 //   In the FirstViewController

- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender{

    SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle: nil];
 second.secString = firstString;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
 [second release];

}
```

Here you need to declare in `SecondViewController.h` file:

```
NSString *secString;
```

and then create a `@property`

```
@property (non atomic,strong) NSString *secString;
```

In `SecondViewController.m` you need to `@synthesize` the `secString`:

```
@synthesize secString;
```

Hence this way you also create a getter and setter for secString by creating property and synthesizing it.

Now you can easily access the `secString` and you can use it anywhere in SecondViewController.

Just to check Try and check if value of firstString is passed to secString, write following code on `viewWillAppear:` of `SecondViewController`

```
NSLog(@"secString: %@",secString);
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Hope this helps.