# ios Pass an object between more than 2 view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

I have my classe which contains my data *Data*
I created my object in my first View called *ViewController*
I will create others viewControllers and I want to read and write datas in the object "man1" created in my ViewController. 
How can I do that ? 
Thank you very much.

This is my code so far:

## Data.H

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Data : NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
    int age;
    NSString *city;
}
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)aName ;

- (NSString*) name;
- (int) age;
- (NSString*) city;

//- (void) setPrenom:(NSString*) prenom;
- (void) setName:(NSString*) newName;
- (void) setAge:(int) newAge;
- (void) setCity:(NSString*) newCity;

@end
```

## Data.m

```
#import "Data.h"

@implementation Data


- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)aName
{
    if ((self = [super init]))

    {
    self.name = aName;

}
    return self;

}


//getter
- (NSString*) name
{
    return name;
}

- (int) age{
    return age;

}

- (NSString*) city{
    return city;
}


//setter
- (void) setName:(NSString*)newName
{
    name = newName;
}
- (void) setAge:(int) newAge
{
    age = newAge;
}
- (void) setCity:(NSString *)newCity
{
    city = newCity;
}



@end
```

## ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Data.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    int testint;

}


@property (readwrite) Data *man1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelAff;


@end
```

## ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Data.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize man1 = _man1;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    NSString * name1 = @"Bob";
    _man1 = [[Data alloc]initWithName:name1  ];
    NSLog(@" %@ ", _man1.name);

    [_man1 setAge:29];
    NSLog(@" %d ", _man1.age);


    [_man1 setCity:@"Tapei"];
    _labelAff.text = [_man1 city];

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not going to work, because you allocate a new instance of `Data` each time a view is loaded, and because each view controller gets its own `Data` object.

One approach to fixing this is [making your `Data` class a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11945106/335858). Your view controllers will be accessing a single instance of `Data`, ensuring that the information is shared among the view controllers:

Data.h

```
@interface Data : NSObject 
{
    NSString *name;
    int age;
    NSString *city;
}
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)aName ;

- (NSString*) name;
- (int) age;
- (NSString*) city;

- (void) setName:(NSString*) newName;
- (void) setAge:(int) newAge;
- (void) setCity:(NSString*) newCity;
+(Data*)instance;
@end
```

Data.m

```
@implementation Data

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)aName {
    if(self=[super init]) {
        ...
    }
    return self;
}

+(Data*)instance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static Data *sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithName: ...];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
@end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will fix this problem first

Comment: I use a singleton for my object but I still don't know how to share datas between View controllers

Comment: @MaxPuis Replace calls of `[[Data alloc]initWithName:name1]` with `[Data instance]` in your view controllers.

Comment: Thank you, it's what I did. And I used this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9954175/2952884 to send write in my object, but it doesn't work

Comment: Should I use delegates ?

Comment: @MaxPuis If you use `[Data instance]`, the data should be shared among your controllers. There are no notifications, but you do not usually need it, unless multiple controllers are on the screen at the same time (which may happen if your app is running on an iPad). In all other cases, it is sufficient to add code to your `viewWillAppear` that re-reads the data for your `_labelAff.text` from your `_man1` object. Currently, you do that in `viewDidLoad`, which happens only once.

Comment: What should I write to an other controller to get the datas?

Comment: @MaxPuis Write code in `viewWillAppear` to access `[Data instance]`, and pull the data from there into the visuals (labels, text fields, etc.)